# Raspberry Pi javaFx Displaylink framebuffer

Tags: linux, javafx, raspberry-pi, framebuffer

I want to use my Raspberry Pi with a javaFx GUI on a USB Displaylink Display. I build my own kernel an enabled the displaylink framebuffer support. When I start the Raspberry the display gets the framebuffer fb1 and the output of the javaFx program is on fb0.
How can I set the output of the javaFx program to the displaylink device. Is there any other solution than to copy the content of fb0 to fb1. 
The X server has the option to start with fb1 "FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 startx", is there something similar possible with javaFx.